# Is it possible to change the parameter of a method that I override in java, or do I need to overload it?

Tags: java

```
public class Employee{
    private String fullName;
    private String phone;
    private String mail;
}

public class Academician extends Employee{
    private String branch;
}

public class EmployeeManager{
    public void login(Employee employee){
        System.out.println(employe.getFullName() + " logged in.")
    }
}

public class AcademicianManager extends EmployeeManager{
    @Override
    public void login(Academician academican){
        System.out.println("Academician " + academican.getFullName() + " logged in.")
    }
}
```

As above, when an employee logs into the system, I want to send private messages and transactions to him, likewise, when an academic logs into the system, I want to do this.

When I use it like this, I get the following error:
*Method does not override method from its superclass*

Comment: If you change the parameter type then you are not overriding the method, you are overloading it. Is using an overload of this method an option?

Comment: "*Is it possible to change the parameter of a method that I override in java, or do I need to overload it?*" - "*When I use it like this, I get the following error: Method does not override method from its superclass*" --- Doesn't that already answer your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify your base class with a T in parameter:

```
public class EmployeeManager<T extends Employee>{
    public void login (T employee){
        System.out.println(employee.getFullName() + " logged in.")
    }
}
```

Then define your child class like this:

```
public class AcademicianManager extends EmployeeManager<Academician>
```